# How to compute initial weights of SMC, when you initialize the algorithm with MCMC draws

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, particle-filter, weights

Let $$y_t | \alpha_t \sim N(0, \exp(\alpha_t)), \\
\alpha_t = \phi_0 + \phi_1\alpha_{t-1} + \sigma \epsilon_t, \\
\text{ where } \epsilon_t \sim N(0,1) \text{ i.i.d.},\\
t=1,2,\cdots,T$$

The unknown parameters are $\{ \alpha_{0:T}, \phi_0, \phi_1,\sigma^2 \}. $ I use the first `t` observations to estimate $\{ \alpha_{0:t}, \phi_0, \phi_1,\sigma^2 \}$ using MCMC and then continue the estimation using SMC methods.

My question is, in order to work with SMC I need to compute initial weights of the unknwown parameters. Please, could you explain to me how to find them?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you first run MCMC, shouldn't the initial weights be one?